# a href tag to place a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have to place a link to a webpage through an `<a>` .The webpage link contains some request parameters and I don't want to send it across through the browser directly (meaning I want to use something similar to POST method of FORM).

```
<a href="www.abc.do?a=0&b=1&c=1>abc</a>
```

I am using this inside a jsp page and is there a way to post it through javascript or any other way where I don't pass the request parameters through the url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use links to submit hidden forms, if that's what you're asking.

```
<a href="#" onclick="submitForm('secretData')">Click Me</a>

<form id="secretData" method="post" action="foo.php" style="display:none">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitForm(formID) {
    document.getElementById(formID).submit();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers? Tsk Tsk.. :) +1 Great answer

Comment: @Doug: Meh, a bit lazy tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `form` tag with hidden fields to submit your data:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.frm.submit(); return false">GO !!</a>

 <form name="frm" action="www.abc.do" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" value="your-data" name="whatever">
   <input type="hidden" value="your-data" name="whatever">
   <input type="hidden" value="your-data" name="whatever">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for that. For example, with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can use the [post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
<a href="#" id="myMagicLink">clickMe</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#myMagicLink").click(function(){
    $.post("www.abc.do", {"a":0, "b":1, "c":1});
  });
});
```

Comment: NO Ajax .Plain  javascript only

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't aware AJAX wasn't "plain JavaScript." Unless by plain you mean without a framework. You could make a more re-usable solution using jQuery to pull attributes from an <a> tag and construct the POST request without using hidden forms, while preserving the <a> tag to redirect to an error page for people who don't have JavaScript enabled. That's just my $.02, though.